# Deploy .NET core website as an application inside .NET framework website in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, deployment

I have a web application developed in .NET core. I need to deploy this application inside an existing website which is in .NET framework as an "Application" I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61388242/iis-host-a-net-core-application-under-net-framework-website). But this does not work.

What I want to do...
[image]

If I run this application, it always throws ERR_CONNECTION_RESET or Too many redirects. But if I publish it as a separate website on a different port, it works. But, I cannot deploy it on a different port due to circumstances. I need the application to be inside this deployed website

Comment: You can try to deploy application contents to site's virtual directory of iis, then convert the virtual directory to application and this should work, this link should help you understand the concepts: [Understanding Sites, Applications, and Virtual Directories on IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis).

Comment: Does not work..

Comment: Do use failed request tracing or other tools to learn what are the redirection responses (from which URL to which URL). That should lead you to the right ASP.NET Core setting to change.

Comment: Did you want to host multiple domains under one site? if so, you can refer to this link: [Hosting multiple domains under one site](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site).

Comment: Not multiple domains. The website to be www.mydomain.com/corewebsite

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Right-click on the Default Web Site, select "Add application" option.

- "Alias" the name given in this field will be used in the URL to
  access this child application
- "Physical Path" location application source code

[image]

Click ok then child application is created in the iis server, you can access this "corewebsite" application as `www.mydmain.com/corewebsite`.

Comment: These all were already tried

Comment: Please post the details of the error page.

Comment: As mentioned in the question - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET or Too many redirects in the browser

Comment: I know, but can you post a screenshot of error? Or check for other error messages in the Event Viewer.